# TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, super

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.bttnClicks = 0
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.bttn = Button(self)
        self.bttn["text"] = "number of clicks"
        self.bttn["command"] = self.upadteClicks
        self.bttn.grid()


    def upadteClicks(self):
        self.bttnClicks += 1
        self.bttn["text"] = "number of clicks " + str(self.bttnClicks)

root = Tk()
root.title("button that do something")
root.geometry("400x200")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()`
```

That's the error:

```
super(Application, self).__init__(master)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

What am I doing wrong? The code worked fine in python 3.XX but in python 2.XX it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Frame` is not a new-style class, but `super` requires new-style classes to work. In python-3.x where everything is a new-style class the `super` will work properly.

You need to hardcode the superclass and method in python 2:

```
Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

Like they do in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tkinter.html#the-window-manager).

Answer (score 0):

`TKinter.Frame` is an old-style class on Python 2. Features like `super` won't work with it. Refer to `Frame.__init__` directly:

```
Frame.__init__(self, master)
```